# Why is my release() method not waking my instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, notify

I've written an example program to demonstrate my problem.
There's a bartender thread and three customer threads.
They run at the same time once created.
The bartender is suppose to serve each customer a drink.

My problem is that the wait() method within the Bartender classes run() method never awakens.
I had intended for the release() method within the run() method of each Customer class to awaken it but it doesn't seem to be working. It never awakens.

How can I go about fixing this?
Thanks to anyone who can offer advice or code snippets.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Bar {

    Semaphore serving;
    boolean isServing = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        serving = new Semaphore(1);
        Thread bartender = new Thread(new Bartender());
        bartender.start();
        threadSleep(1000);

        Thread customer1 = new Thread(new Customer());
        customer1.start();
        threadSleep(2000);
        Thread customer2 = new Thread(new Customer());
        customer2.start();
        threadSleep(2000);
        Thread customer3 = new Thread(new Customer());
        customer3.start();
    }

    public void threadSleep(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Bar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public class Bartender implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (serving.availablePermits() == 0) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Waiting for Customer notify");
                            wait();
                            System.out.println("Serve drink");
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Bar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Customer implements Runnable {
        private boolean customerServed = false;

        public void run() {
            if (!customerServed) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        serving.acquire();
                        if (serving.availablePermits() == 0 && !serving.hasQueuedThreads()) {
                            notify();
                            isServing = true;
                            System.out.println("Customer: Recieves drink");
                            customerServed = true;
                            serving.release();
                            isServing = false;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Bar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `class Bartender` and `class Customer`

change `synchronized (this) {` to `synchronized (Bar.this) {`

change `wait()` to `Bar.this.wait()`

change `notify()` to `Bar.this.notify()`

Because two `this` refer to different object, `Bartender` never wakes up. And because two `Bar.this` refer to same object, `Bartender` will wake up!

Comment: Thank you
I made your changes but that's resulting in an Exception being thrown at runtime.
 java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: @James I mistakenly forgot something. I have already fixed it.